# Solaris Guest VM on Ubuntu 14.04 KVM Setup, unable to get DHCP IP nor able to reach network

Tags: 14.04, networking, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, solaris

I have a solaris VM running on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS KVM.

I'm using bridged networking. VM is unable to get an IP address, on sending DHCP request I can see requests going through bridge `br0` and replies coming on `br0`, but it is not reaching the VM.

I have also flushed (`iptables -F`) all the rules, still packets not reaching VM!

Below is my network configuration on Ubuntu Host:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual

auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
        bridge_ports eth0
        bridge_fd 9
        bridge_hello 2
        bridge_maxage 12
        bridge_stp off
```

Comment: Same VM worked on a CentOS 6.5 Host.
On using libvirt default networking i see the same issue, able to send packets but unable to receive it.

Answer (score 1):

Few findings from my side:

1. Booted Plain Opensolaris VM, found same issue!
2. Checked with qemu's site on supported OSes, Solaris 11 Express 2010.11 is supported but with few issues.
3. Then found this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/qemu/+bug/1395217

**Solution**: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1040500